# How to Cluster Sequential Categorical Data in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

Consider a data set where users can choose among 3 activities, and we have the data for the choice of their first 10 activities. Example data:

```
for (i in 1:10) 
{
  # sample from list of 3 strings using a set probability
  x <- sample( c("A", "B", "C"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2) )
  # assign to variable created on the fly
  assign( paste("cat", i, sep=""), x )
}

first10 <- data.frame(cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5, cat6, cat7, cat8, cat9, cat10)
```

What's the best approach in R to cluster users according to their activity sequence?

I've looked around on stackoverflow, and the most similar questions ask about how to cluster categorical data in R (which is part of the analysis), but this in and of itself doesn't account for the sequential nature of the data. Are there R packages that are well-suited for this analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Look for frequent itemset mining instead of clustering.

Most clustering methods are for continuous numerical data, and assume some vector field. They take every position into account.

A frequent pattern, however, may be only part if a sequence, a sequence may exhibit multiple (or none) of these patterns, and patterns may have gaps inbetween. All of these properties are usually desirable.

Comment: There are also methods for clustering categorical data, such as Rmixmod or clustering a distance matrix based on Gower's distance. Oftentimes, we have a mixed data set where clustering is desirable. See for example: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/robust-cluster-method-for-mixed-data-in-r

I think the suggested method is interesting, but it's addressing a different question. It's the equivalent of looking for highly correlated variables in a continuous data set (or perhaps using a factor analysis), but that's different from creating a classification model for the cases.